# use `const char thing[] = "foo";` in a header file?

Tags: c++, dry, one-definition-rule

I want to create a constant global char array such that

- It can be used in multiple translation units.
- The length of the array is deduced from the string literal used to initialize it.
- That string literal exist exactly once in my source (and if possible the object files).
- Where all the translation unit have compile time access to the length.
- Has no ODR violations when the multiple translation units are linked together.

In theory this should be possible by using `const char[]` and putting the deceleration/definition in the header file in a way that forces the data/symbol into a COMDAT section, but I don't know if the standard (or even any compilers) support that.

p.s. Assume whatever idiom is used will be used for hundreds to thousands of constants across many files.

---

Edit: the "cleanest" solution I know of that give all the points is:

```
template<bool> struct data_ {
  static const char kFoo[];
};

template<> const char data_<true>::kFoo[] = "bar\0other\0stuff\0";
typedef data_<true> data;


#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T, int N>
void Print(T(&var)[N]) { printf("%d %s\n", N, var); }

int main() { Print(data::kFoo); return 0; }
```

Which is still rather ugly.

---

OTOH If I just throw out 3b (guaranteed same storage module inlineing) then this work:

```
const char kFoo[] = "bar\0other\0stuff\0";
```

because it's has internal linkage by default. A good linker could merge these, but at that point you can't say anything about the the relationship between the equality of the addresses/identifiers (i.e. don't cast it to a pointer and use that as an identity). But that's a caveat that's likely to be benign *almost* all of the time.

Comment: In a header file, such a variable (`const` but not `extern`) will get internal linkage, meaning that there will be a different object in each translation unit.

Comment: I think you can use either a static data member of a class template or a static local variable inside an inline function to fulfil those requirements.

Comment: Another interesting idea could be to store the string literal address and the length separately, and let the linker merge those string literals.

Comment: `const` & not `extern` fails point 3b. The template solution is ugly and requires repeating the name and most of the type. The function-static solution requires auto return type (c++14, not yet) or fails point 4. I'm not sure how separate storage could get all of point's 2, 3a and 4.

Comment: While I don't normally advocate the use of the Singleton pattern, making a Singleton class which encapsulates the string literal should satisfy all of your requirements with the exception maybe of requirement 4.) "Where all the translation units have compile time access to the length", but there might still be some way to enforce that.

Comment: `template<size_t N> struct str_lit { char const* s; }; template<size_t N> str_lit<N> make_str_lit(char const (&s)[N]) { return {s}; }` then `constexpr auto s = make_str_lit("hello world");` This relies on the linker merging all the `"hello world"` string literals. I think it is not possible to get rid of the pointer, but it might be possible to prevent odr-usage of it.

Comment: Standard C++ makes no guarantee about how much storage is used; it's up to your compiler/linker

Answer (score 2):

Header:

```
#define LITERAL "Hello, world"
extern char const literal[sizeof LITERAL];
```

One source file:

```
char const literal[] = LITERAL;
```

There's still no guarantee that any particular compiler/linker only make one copy of the string literal (but it does guarantee the requirement that `&literal[0]` is the same in all units).

Comment: macros and repeated identifiers across files or templates and repeated identifiers in a single file... :-(

Comment: @BCS Huh? This satisfies all your listed conditions and I have no idea what you mean by "repeated identifiers in a single file" (which isn't one of your conditions)

Comment: the template solution (included in the question) has the identifier being declared showing up in several places in the boilerplate (as does your solution) but they can all be placed in a single file. tl;dr; I now know several ways to make this work and all are ugly.

Comment: Mine only has the identifier in two places (one .h file and one .cpp file). You could use preprocessing hacks to get this down to one, but you did not list that as a requirement and I don't see why you think it makes a difference.

Comment: Your's does fit all the requirements I stated. However it is still, IMHO, inelegant. Or to put it another way: I don't *like* it, or any of the other options. There is a good chance I won't like anything that doesn't require changing the language.

Comment: OK. A matter of opinion I guess, I would consider this far more elegant than a pile of templates :)

Comment: @BCS Well, “changing the language” has now happened.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++17 you can write in the header:

```
inline char const thing[] = "foo";
```

which meets all the criteria.

*Note:* `inline` variables have external linkage unless explicitly declared as `static`.  The rule about `const` variables defaulting to internal linkage only applies to non-inline variables.

Comment: You still need `extern`, since this is a variable and not a function (otherwise they might not be merged by the linker).

Comment: @DanielH `thing` in my code has external linkage already  (see [basic.link]/4.1)

Comment: You are correct. I remembered something like that but couldn’t find the reference, so assumed I misremembered. Turns out it was right below where I looked.

Answer (score -3):

don't u want

```
const char * const LITERAL="foo";
```

Comment: No, I think that is either an ODR violation or results in storing "foo" more than once in the binary. Besides, the code can't get the size of the array at compile time. (Consider if the string contains `\0` or the length is used as a template parameter.)

Comment: No ODR violation, `LITERAL` has internal linkage.

Comment: The hits all marks except one, assuming the toolchain is properly configured to merge duplicate string literals (a not-uncommon configuration option). The one missing: the length of the array being deduced from the string literal. I.e. application of `sizeof(LITERAL)` is not going to give the result the OP is seeking.

Comment: Just to be difficult, I'm going to say that the "exactly once" requirement is that pointer comparisons between the strings from different units be well defined to be equal (a conforming compiler is required to ensure that be true)